# Написать структуру двусвязного списка JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как устроен двусвязный список, не пойму как ссылается prev. Было б круто написать код двусвязного списка, как ниже написан односвязный. Спасибо!

````
let list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень удобно показать как устроен двусвязный список таким же образом, как у вас односвязный. Думаю картинкой будет понятно:

[image: Не очень по качеству картинка.]

То есть все просто `next` указывает на следующий элемент, а `prev` на предыдущий.

[Тут](https://frontend-stuff.com/blog/doubly-linked-lists-with-javascript/#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20JavaScript.&text=%D0%94%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%20-%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85,%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20(%20next%20)%20%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BB.) вы можете найти реализацию с пояснением.

Comment: Вот по картинке я понимаю как он устроен, и на сайте я уже был, тот на который ссылку указали. Ну вот в голове не пойму как организовать prev. В любом случае спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: Как понять "_организовать prev_"? Что конкретно вы не понимаете? `next` это тоже самое, только в обратную сторону.

Comment: например, value: 1, next { value: 2, next: null} здесь понятно что доступ к памяти мы получаем обращаясь к node.next, и мы получаем ссылку на следующий обьект, а как закодировать prev?) Каким образом мы получаем ссылку на память.

Comment: Ладно, понял что node.prev ссылается напрямую к node. И так как организован односвязный список в примере , так нельзя написать двусвязный. Ваша аватарка описывает ситуацию xD. Cпасибо)

Comment: @РомаДовгалюк  У вас есть два объекта с `value: 1` и `value: 2`. У первого объекта `prev = null` думаю понятно, у второго `prev` должен указывать на первый объект. Точно так же как `next` у первого указывает на второй объект. То есть `prev = первый объект`

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант AList.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, previous = null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}

class Llist {
    constructor() {
        this._length = 0;
        this._head = null;
        this._last = null;
    }
    addItems(...arr) {
        if (arr.length === 1) {
            this._head = new Node(arr[0]);
            this._last = this._head;
            this._length++;
        } else if (arr.length > 1) {
            this._head = new Node(arr[0]);
            this._last = this._head;
            this._length++;
            let currentNode = this._head;
            for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                currentNode.next = new Node(arr[i], currentNode);
                this._length++;
                this._last = currentNode.next;
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    push(value) {
        if (!this._head) {
            this._head = new Node(value);
            this._last = this._head;
        } else {
            this._last = this._last.next = new Node(value, this._last);
        }
        this._length++;
        return value;
    }
    pop() {
        if (!this._head) {
            new Error("LinkedList empty. Please use Llist.pop() or Llist.addItems() for add item")
        } else {
            let value = this._last.value;
            if (this._length === 1) {
                this._head = null;
                this._last = null;
                this._length = 0;
            } else {
                this._last = this._last.previous;
                this._last.next = null;
                this._length--;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    shift() {
        if (!this._head) {
            console.log(new Error("LinkedList empty. Please use Llis.pop() or Llist.addItems() for add item"))
        } else {
            let value = this._head.value;
            if (this._length === 1) {
                this._head = null;
                this._last = null;
                this._length = 0;
            } else {
                this._head = this._head.next;
                this._head.previous = null;
                this._length--;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    unshift(value) {
        if (this._length === 0) {
            this._head = new Node(value);
            this._last = this._head;
            this._length++;
        } else {
            let nextNode = this._head
            this._head = new Node(value);
            nextNode.previous = this._head;
            this._head.next = nextNode;
            this._length++;
        }
    }
    getItem(index) {
        let currentNode = this._head;
        if (index === 0) {
            return currentNode.value;
        } else if (index >= this._length) {
            return null;
        }
        for (let i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return currentNode.value;
    }

    splice(start, end = this._length - 1) {

        let currentNodeStart = this._head;
        for (let i = 0; i < start - 1; i++) {
            currentNodeStart = currentNodeStart.next;
        }
        let currentNodeEnd = currentNodeStart;
        if (end === this._length - 1 || end === 0) {
            currentNodeEnd.previous = currentNodeStart.previous;
            currentNodeStart.next = null;
            let currentNode = this._head;
            this._length = 0;
            while (currentNode) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
                this._length++;
            }
            this._last = currentNodeStart;
            return this._head;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
            currentNodeEnd = currentNodeEnd.next;
        }

        if (start === 0) {
            this._head = currentNodeEnd;
        } else {
            currentNodeStart.next = currentNodeEnd;
        }

        currentNodeEnd.previous = currentNodeStart;

        let currentNode = this._head;
        this._length = 0;
        while (currentNode) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
            this._length++;
        }
        return this._head;
    }

    toArray() {
        let arr = [];
        let currentNode = this._head;
        while (currentNode) {
            arr.push(currentNode.value);
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return arr;
    }
    get length() {
        return this._length;
    }
}

let d = new Llist();
console.log(d);
d.push(2)
d.push(3)
console.log(d);
```